# Induction proof: Prove that $(1+x)^n \geq \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}x^3$ for $n\geq 3$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

I'm stuck on this proof. I assume it's supposed to be an induction proof, but I cannot figure out how to algebraically prove that $(1+x)^{k+1}\geq \frac{(k+1)(k)(k-1)}{6}x^3$. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: it's easy to prove that
$(1+x)^3\geq \frac{3(3-1)(3-2)}{6}x^3$,
since the right hand side is equal to $x^3$, and it's easy to see that
$(1+x)^3\geq x^3$.

I'm stuck on understanding how to relate the assumption that 
$(1+x)^k\geq \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{6}x^3$
to the inequality needed, that
$(1+x)^{k+1}\geq \frac{(k+1)k(k-1)}{6}x^3$, 
in order to prove that $P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)$ is true.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset mathematical formulas on this website. I have improved your post with this change.

Comment: Is $x$ positive?

Comment: Yes, x is positive. And thank you.

Comment: I don't think induction is the right approach here (at least not directly like what you are doing).  The binomial theorem is glaring at me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $x$ is positive, this follows immediatelly from the Binomial theorem.

If you want to use induction, you can prove easily the **stronger** statement
$$(1+x)^k \geq 1+kx+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}x^2+\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{6}x^3 \hskip{1cm} \forall k \geq 3$$

**Added:** The inductive step

$$(1+x)^{k+1}=(1+x)^k(1+x) \geq (1+kx+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}x^2+\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{6}x^3)(1+x)$$
with the inequality following from $P(k)$ and $1+x \geq 0$.

Now, just expand the RHS, and use the fact that the term $\alpha x^4 \geq 0$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Yes, ty.

Comment: When using induction to solve things like the statement above, is it considered legitimate to, instead of using a "k" and "k+1", let k+2=m, such that we can use m+1? I guess I'm asking because I'm still having issues with the proof by induction, seeing as there are negative terms that I'm having many issues with negative terms.

Comment: @ThePikleCowWithSunglasses What negative terms? I'll expand a bit. See the addon.

Comment: I suppose I just want to clarify, simply because I've been working on this and gotten very few places with it. For the inductive step, do I need to prove that

Comment: I suppose I just want to clarify, simply because I've been working on this and gotten very few places with it. For the inductive step, do I need to prove that $$(1+kx+(k(k−1)/2)*x^2+(k(k−1)(k−2)/6)*x^3)*(1+x) \geq 1 + (k+1)x + ((k+1)(k)/2)*x^2 + ((k+1)(k)(k-1)/6)*x^3$$

Comment: @ThePikleCowWithSunglasses Yes. Try expanding the LHS. The free term is 1. The coefficient of $x$ is $k+1$. The coefficient of $x^2$ is $k(k-1)/2+k$ which is equal to $k(k+1)/2$ and so on.

Comment: So would an efficient strategy be to compare the RHS and LHS term by term? For example, $$1(x+1) \geq 1$$, $$(x+1)(kx) \geq (k+1)x$$, and so on? Just prove the inequality term by term? I guess I'm just confused when you say that the coefficient of $x^2$ is $k(k-1)/2 + k$. Is that in the LHS of the inequality introduced in my previous comment?

Comment: @ThePikleCowWithSunglasses Just calculate the Polynomial which is the LHS, by EXPANDING. You will see that up to degree 3 you get exactly the RHS.  To prove the inequality all you need to do is show that the difference LHS-RHS is positive.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I don't know how I didn't see this before!